# Using Gerrit to restrict read access to a git branch

Tags: gerrit

I'm beginning to suspect that this is not possible.  I was hoping that I could set up custom access control in Gerrit so that a particular role (defined in TF) would not have read access to a specific branch in a repo.

However, it appears that users with this role are unable to clone the repo at all.  I was hoping they'd be able to clone and just not beb able to check out the restricted branch.

Just wondering if anyone else has enountered this and might be able to confirm the behaviour I'm seeing.  I did see another thread here recommending gitolite for partial copies but I'm restricted to using TF/Gerrit.

Thanks!

Comment: What's TF? You can deny access to any refs, like `refs/heads/secret-branch`. Not sure, if that's really secure - not sure, but it might download the commits (in pack files), so the actual contents might be visible, just not the pointer to them.

Comment: TF = TeamForge.  Thanks Stephen.  I have a couple of other options which are easier to manage (keeping restricted branches in seperate projets for collaboration activities, etc.) which I think I'll stick with!